# How to invert/flip screen on windows xp?

Tags: windows-xp, display

How can I invert the screen on Windows XP? Not rotate, but flip/invert horizontally? I want the text, and everything else on the screen, to go from right to left.

Comment: How about placing a mirror next to the screen `:-)`.

Comment: nice :D but i dont have mirror :)

Comment: Is this about a prank? :-)

Comment: Its not a prank. I need it.

Comment: Could you please explain why you need something like this? Other users might have a better way to achieve the same result, something you haven't thought of?

Comment: It's really useful when videoing yourself as your then your image appears as if in a mirror which most people are much more familiar with.  My Sony Handycam does this automatically if I swivel the display to face the subject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the video card drivers. I've used this option from the nVidia and Intel video cards settings, but they're different from one manufacturer to the other.

**Edit**: for an nVidia card you could try NVRotate (it should come with the video card driver). If this doesn't work, just try [iRotate](http://www.entechtaiwan.com/util/irotate.shtm); it's a free, very small (125KB) app that does what you need.

Comment: been there. done that. it doesnt have such function. only rotate and etc :(

Comment: Really? what video card do you have?

Comment: GeForce 8800 GT

Comment: Try the suggestion made in my edit. Hope this actually helps :)

Comment: @alex: you did not get the question. Its not working with iRotate. We use to flip the screen, and then we use a mirror for News channels. In Linux we can do it but with Windows its being for a while impossible. Can you please clarify the question and post some reliable answer?

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl-Alt-[Up Arrow], if your video card supports it.